# When and where do you close a PDDocument?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I get bytearrays of several pdfs from a backend source.
I load all these bytearrays into PDDocuments and add them to a list, like this:

```
List<PDDocument> pdfs = new ArrayList<>();
for (...the amount of bytearrays...) {
    PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(bytearray);
    pdfs.add(pdf);
}
```

I then merge these pdfs into one PDDocument:

```
PDDocument mergedPdf = new PDDocument();
PDFMergerUtility PDFmerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
for(...all pdfs in list...) {
    PDFmerger.appendDocument(mergedPdf, pdf);
}
```

And then I save the mergedPdf to a file:

```
mergedPdf.save("c:\temp\mergeddoc.pdf");
```

My question is now: where do I call the close() method on these pddocuments?
Is this after loading them? But then that means I can't work any further with them, because I have closed the pdfs.
Or is this only needed at the end after I do the save?

Comment: Does Tilman's answer sufficiently answer your question? Or are there still open points? I wonder because you haven't marked his answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the safest side if you call `close()` on the source documents after saving the destination document. There have been bugs in older PDFBox 2.0.* versions where the destination PDF still kept references on the source PDFs - usually these were tagged PDFs. The soon to be released (likely in March) version 2.0.14 has all of these bugs fixed, hopefully, and you can close the source PDF after calling `appendDocument()`. Obviously you can't call `close()` directly after loading because the document is needed for `appendDocument()`.